# Stat summary for each factor in scatter plot ggplot2: What about fun.x, fun_y combinations?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a bunch of data for people touching bacteria for up to 5 touches. I'm comparing how much they pick up with and without gloves. I'd like to plot the mean by the factor NumberContacts and colour it red. E.g. the red dots on the following graphs.
[image]

So far I have:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(reshape2)
```

**Make some data**

```
    df<-data.frame(Yes=rnorm(n=100),
No=rnorm(n=100),
NumberContacts=factor(rep(1:5, each=20)))
```

**Calculate the mean for each group= NumberContacts**

```
centroids<-aggregate(data=melt(df,id.vars ="NumberContacts"),value~NumberContacts+variable,mean)
```

**Get them into two columns**

```
centYes<-subset(centroids, variable=="Yes",select=c("NumberContacts","value"))
centNo<-subset(centroids, variable=="No",select="value")
centroids<-cbind(centYes,centNo)
colnames(centroids)<-c("NumberContacts","Gloved","Ungloved")
```

**Make an ugly plot.**

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=gloves,y=ungloved)+
  geom_point()+
  geom_abline(slope=1,linetype=2)+
  stat_ellipse(type="norm",linetype=2,level=0.975)+
  geom_point(data=centroids,size=5,color='red')+
  #stat_summary(fun.y="mean",colour="red")+ doesn't work
  facet_wrap(~NumberContacts,nrow=2)+
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Is there a more elegant way by using stat_summary? Also How can I change the look of the boxes at the top of my graphs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stat_summary` is not an option because (see `?stat_summary`):

> stat_summary operates on **unique x**

That is, while we can take a mean of `y`, `x` remains fixed. But we may do something else that is very concise:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Yes, y = No, group = NumberContacts)) +
  geom_point() + geom_abline(slope = 1, linetype = 2)+
  stat_ellipse(type = "norm", linetype = 2, level = 0.975)+
  geom_point(data = df %>% group_by(NumberContacts) %>% summarise_all(mean), size = 5, color = "red")+ 
  facet_wrap(~ NumberContacts, nrow = 2) + theme_classic() + 
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(fill = "black"),
        strip.text = element_text(color = "white"))
```

[image]

which also shows that to modify the boxes above you want to look at `strip` [elements](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme.html) of `theme`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense! Already with the black top, the graphs look better.